# Laptop sound stuck displaying both Headphone/Non-headphone mode

Tags: windows-7, audio, headphones

I just unplugged my headphones from my laptop, and the Win7 sound tool gives me 2 separate volume bars. One for headphone and one regular one. The only time I've ever seen this happen was when having TeamSpeak installed on an older computer of mine.

Now, some flash videos are on headphone, others aren't. Same for various applications. Totally random.

No idea at all what triggered this. Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of HP notebooks. When you connect headphones, jack is moved slightly from its position. The solution is: take a stick ear and slide it into the jack on the left and right to hear music from the internal speakers. Alternatively use the headphone jack and make circular moves around the headphones jack untill you find the sweet spot that the sound will come back.

Comment: Nice observation there....
+1